# Views expose filter with ajax showing validation message after reloading page?

Tags: 7, views

I added a date filter that showing select list for `year` and `month`. I created the block type view. When I select the `month` and submit the form it makes the red border outside the `year`. But when I reload the page or go to another page it gives me the error :

```
Please choose a year.
```

How to show error message at the time of form submit?

Any Solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue too recently. I didn't try the javascript solution posted above, because I found this thread on d.o that seemed to solve the issue for me, so thought I would add it here as another option: https://www.drupal.org/node/1833322#comment-9184301

Specifically, the comment provides this code:

```
function MODULE_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view) {
  $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend($commands[0]['selector'], theme('status_messages'));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was an old issue. I just applied whatever solution clicked to my mind. Thanks for posting your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the **Ajax for exposed filter**, It will show only the message on form submit.

[image]

Comment: Where is this option? Do I need to install bef?

Comment: @SumitMadan I updated the answer with screenshot

Comment: I can't disable it. I displayed the view using https://drupal.org/project/viewreference. If I disabled the ajax it takes me to origional url of view and my other configuration of page will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using custom javascript code.

```
    jQuery(".views-exposed-form #edit-date-filter-value-year").live('change',function(){
    jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').removeClass("error");
    var month=jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').val(); 
    if(jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').val()==""){
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').addClass("error");
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '#dedede');
    } 
    else if(month=="") {
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').focus();
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').addClass("error"); 
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '#dedede');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '');
    }
});

jQuery('.views-exposed-form #edit-date-filter-value-month').live('change',function(){
    jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').removeClass("error");
    var year=jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').val(); 
    if(jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').val()==""){
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-month').addClass("error");
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '#dedede');
    }
    else if(year=="") {
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').focus();
        jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-year').addClass("error"); 
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '#dedede');
    }
    else{
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        jQuery('input[type="submit"]').css('background', '');
    }
});
```